# ¿Cómo obtener clave SHA-1 de certificado instalado en dispositivo Android?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.android, firma-digital

Estoy desarrollando una App en Xamarin.Android en la cual tengo que firmar un PDF utilizando Firma Digital. Tengo instalado un certificado en una tablet que uso para hacer las pruebas.
El certificado pude instalarlo sin ningún tipo de problema, pero lo que no sé ahora es cómo puedo obtener los datos de ese certificado para poder firmar el documento.

Alguien podría guiarme?
Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Finalmente no pude encontrar manera de utilizar los certificados que instalé en el dispositivo, por ende tuve que copiar físicamente el certificado en la tablet y utilizarlo sin instalarlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente no pude encontrar manera de utilizar los certificados que instalé en el dispositivo, por eso mismo lo que hice fue copiar físicamente el certificado en la tablet y utilizarlo sin instalarlo.

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener el SHA-1 necesitas conocer la ubicación de tu Keystore con el cual firmaste la aplicación, por ejemplo:

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Mono for Android\debug.keystore
```

y mediante la utilería `keytool` de jdk puedes obtener el valor, esta se encuentra generalmente en la ruta:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdkVERSION\bin\keytool.exe
```

Puedes agregar el directorio que contiene `keytool.exe` a la variable de entorno `PATH` para que desde la linea de comandos puedas ejecutar `keytool.exe` o puedes entrar a su ruta y ejecutar el siguiente comando definiendo la ruta de tu 
 `keystore`, así como su alias, keystore password, y key password , ejemplo :

```
keytool.exe -list -v -keystore "%LocalAppData%\Xamarin\Mono for Android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

los datos obtenidos serían similares a :

```
Alias name: androiddebugkey
Creation date: Aug 19, 2014
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 1
Certificate[1]:
Owner: CN=Android Debug, O=Android, C=US
Issuer: CN=Android Debug, O=Android, C=US
Serial number: 53f3b126
Valid from: Tue Aug 19 13:18:46 PDT 2014 until: Sun Nov 15 12:18:46 PST 2043
Certificate fingerprints:
         MD5:  27:78:7C:31:64:C2:79:C6:ED:E5:80:51:33:9C:03:57
         SHA1: 00:E5:8B:DA:29:49:9D:FC:1D:DA:E7:EE:EE:1A:8A:C7:85:E7:31:23
         SHA256: 21:0D:73:90:1D:D6:3D:AB:4C:80:4E:C4:A9:CB:97:FF:34:DD:B4:42:FC:
08:13:E0:49:51:65:A6:7C:7C:90:45
         Signature algorithm name: SHA1withRSA
         Version: 3
```

conteniendo el valor de `SHA1` que necesitas.

Revisa la documentación de Xamarin : [**Encontrar la firma de su Keystore**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/signing/keystore-signature?tabs=vswin)

Comment: Si, pero yo no necesito la firma de la aplicación. Tengo un certificado para Firma Digital instalado en la tablet que es independiente de la App que estoy haciendo, este certificado tiene un SHA1 y SHA256 y son los que necesito para firmar el documento.

Answer (score 0):

Lo más fácil es usar esta extensión de Visual Studio: [Keystore Signature Tool](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Redth.AndroidKeystoreSignatureTool)

Se integra con Visual Studio y te entregará los hashes SHA1, SHA256, MD5 y SHA1 para Facebook. No hay que buscar el keystore de debug, lo encuentra automático.

Una [guía para instalar y usar](https://blog.xamarin.com/simplified-android-keystore-signature-disovery/) escrita por el gran James Montemagno.